# Application stopped and restart after clicking on confirm button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am doing an android development on Eclipse. The application can do the the following things:

- add new assignment
- modify assignment
- delete assignment

Now I encountered a problem is that whenever i tried to delete an assignment, the application will crash right after i click confirm button.

This is the logcat:

```
05-01 06:31:26.772: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:26.912: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:37.582: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:37.772: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:40.232: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:40.682: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:42.662: D/AndroidRuntime(1417): Shutting down VM
05-01 06:31:42.662: W/dalvikvm(1417): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3adeba8)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): Process: com.mada.assignmentmanager, PID: 1417
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.mada.assignmentmanager.AssignmentManagerDatabase.deleteAssignment(AssignmentManagerDatabase.java:91)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.mada.assignmentmanager.AssignmentManagerView$1.onClick(AssignmentManagerView.java:74)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 06:31:42.722: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 166K, 7% free 3914K/4196K, paused 33ms, total 41ms
05-01 06:31:47.922: I/Process(1417): Sending signal. PID: 1417 SIG: 9
05-01 06:31:49.402: D/dalvikvm(1452): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 7% free 2947K/3140K, paused 125ms, total 129ms
05-01 06:31:49.402: I/dalvikvm-heap(1452): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.596MB for 635812-byte allocation
05-01 06:31:49.462: D/dalvikvm(1452): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3565K/3764K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
05-01 06:31:50.292: I/Choreographer(1452): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 06:31:50.322: D/gralloc_goldfish(1452): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

here are my code on the action "delete assignment" :

```
private void deleteAssignment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder dgbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dgbox.setTitle("Confirm to delete");
    dgbox.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this assignment?");

    dgbox.setPositiveButton("Delete",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    final AssignmentManagerDatabase db = new AssignmentManagerDatabase(
                            AssignmentManagerView.this);
                    db.deleteAssignment(assignID);
                    finish();
                }
            }); // setPositiveButton

    // provide a button that simply dismisses the dialog
    dgbox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    dgbox.show();
}
```

from the above code, you can see that i had made a dialog box when i choose to delete an assignment. The app will be stopped and restart again. The selected assignment is not deleted.

I got a menu to select the delete:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuAdd:
        Intent addAssignment = new Intent(this, AssignmentAddNew.class);
        startActivity(addAssignment);
        return true;
    case R.id.menuModify:
        Intent editAssignment = new Intent(this, AssignmentEdit.class);
        startActivity(editAssignment);
        return true;
    case R.id.menuDelete:
        deleteAssignment();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the full database code:

```
package com.mada.assignmentmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AssignmentManagerDatabase {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_MODULECODE = "module_code";
public static final String KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME = "assignment_name";
public static final String KEY_MARKSPROPORTION = "marks_proportion";
public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "due_date";
public static final String KEY_PROGRESS = "_progress";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Assignmentdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AssignmentTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
String cmd;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private static final String CREATE_NEW_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MODULECODE
            + " TEXT  NOT NULL, " + KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_MARKSPROPORTION + " INTEGER, " + KEY_DUEDATE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PROGRESS + " INTEGER);";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NEW_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("AssignmentDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version" + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all the old data.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public AssignmentManagerDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public AssignmentManagerDatabase open() {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public void createEntry(String moduleCode, String assignmentName,
        String marksProportion, String dueDate, String assignmentProgress) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_MODULECODE, moduleCode);
    cv.put(KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME, assignmentName);
    cv.put(KEY_MARKSPROPORTION, marksProportion);
    cv.put(KEY_DUEDATE, dueDate);
    cv.put(KEY_PROGRESS, assignmentProgress);
    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public Cursor getAllAssignments() {
    // String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULECODE,
    // KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME, KEY_MARKSPROPORTION, KEY_DUEDATE, KEY_PROGRESS};
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_DUEDATE };
    return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, KEY_DUEDATE);
}

public void deleteAssignment(long id) {
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
}

public Cursor getOneAssignment(long assignID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + assignID, null, null, null, null);
}

}
```

This is the delete action on my database:

```
    public void deleteAssignment(long id) {
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
}
```

Comment: What is code at line number 91 ?

Comment: This line says that error in deleteAssignment() method

05-01 06:31:42.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.mada.assignmentmanager.AssignmentManagerDatabase.deleteAssignment(AssignmentManagerDatabase.java:91)

Check again, or double click on this line and check it will tell you at where your app crash.

Comment: Line 91@ AssignmentManagerDatabase class. Post the code

Comment: @Prince sorry for posting the wrong code just now. I had uploaded my database code. The Line 91 is ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);

Comment: @Libin i had posted my database code as well as the part on Line 91

Answer (score 0):

```
final Context context = this;
                dgbox.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                    // set title
                    dgbox.setTitle("");

                    // set dialog message
                    dgbox
                        .setMessage("No Records Found!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Exit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    final AssignmentManagerDatabase db = new AssignmentManagerDatabase(
                    AssignmentManagerView.this);
                    db.deleteAssignment(assignID);
                    finish();

                            }
                          });

                        // create alert dialog
                        alertDialog = dgbox.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show()
```

Comment: Hi @Boopathi , thanks for answering my question. =) May I know the Context class is from where? I don't understand that part of the code.

Comment: from here context is current activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to call open() method to open the database before calling deleteAsignment

With out database open call, ourDatabase will be null

```
        final AssignmentManagerDatabase db = new AssignmentManagerDatabase(
                        AssignmentManagerView.this);
        db.open():
                db.deleteAssignment(assignID);
```

Comment: thanks @Libin ^^ I am able to delete the selected assignment now =)